# Topology Homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Let $R$ be endowed with the subspace topology inherited from the euclidean topology.
Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of $R$, where $A=\{3\}∪[4,5]∪\{6\}$ and $B=[3,4]∪\{5\}∪\{6\}.$ 
How do you show that no homeomorphism of $R$ to itself can map $A$ to $B$?

Comment: I assume $R=\mathbb R$ is what you mean. Do you know the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Yes I mean the set of real numbers. I've got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A continuous injection from $\Bbb R$ to itself must be either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. On the other hand it had to map $3$ and $6$ to $5$ and $6$, and $[4,5]$ to $[3,4]$. It is easy to see that no increasing or decreasing map can do this.